# Angular 6 - publish under path not working with direct link

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I have an Angular 6 app that works perfectly fine while developing. Navigation to different routes works well. When I use ng serve -o I can just open the browser and going to http://localhost:4200 works fine ... if in the main page I click login I will go to http://localhost:4200/login ... all good. Even if I don't click the loign button but rather enter in the browser http://localhost:4200/login or any other route it works fine.

Now I have to publish this app under a path: `http://example.com/mypath`. I build this with this command: `ng build --prod --build-optimizer --base-href=/mypath/`, put it to the server and all is good if I use the links within the app to navigate to different routes.

The problem is if I type in the browser the direct url like: `http://example.com/mypath/login`, then it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can add htacccess for that or add useHash property to your routermodule

Comment: @FatehMohamed: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Can you try it using `HashLocationStratergy` like `imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash:true})]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this config in .htaccess for apache or add useHAsh property for routing

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```